# keyboard library not working in python 3.9.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already have pip installed the library but I still get an error saying it is not installed. My code looks like this:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
import keyboard
import time
time.wait(5)
with open('NewFile.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        for char in line:
            if char == '#':
                keyboard.press('enter')
                time.wait(1)
            else:
                keyboard.write(char)
                time.wait(0.05)
```

Comment: Check if pip install keyboard in the correct python environment.

Comment: @dorian turba I'm pretty sure it is

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot argue with the interpreter... Please, provide the full traceback you get, as well as info how your run your code.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\korcz\Discord Spammer\spammerstart.py", line 3, in <module>
    import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'

Comment: I run it from the IDLE

Answer (score 0):

This means the python interpreter cannot find the module that you "installed". Check if you installed it under "Administrator". This works for Linux but it seems you are using Windows. Try to install by opining the command prompt as administrator and installing it again. Based on what you gave us it is hard to pinpoint why the error was generated.

If this does not work try adding more details to the question.

Comment: Also, it is time.sleep() if you are trying to pause